# alter the data format using to_date does not change the number of digits (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, format, dataformat

I am trying to change the date format of the column "yearcode" into four digits (yyyy), since I do not have the specific day for the data.

However, when I check the data format of the column, the table still shows the date format in "yyyy-mm-dd" format.

Here is the code that I wrote in order to change the format:

```
alter table postmaster_compensation alter yearcode type date using to_date('1845','yyyy')
```

I wonder if there's any problem with the code, or I cannot change the format into "yyyy" pattern at all? the 9.6 reference says 'yyyy' is a valid date format.

Thanks!

Comment: `to_date('1845','yyyy')` gives "1845-01-01", not "1845"

Answer (score 0):

If the column should be in char, then change the format of the column to char and get the year using to_char

```
alter table postmaster_compensation alter yearcode type char(4) using to_char('01/01/1845','yyyy')
```

If the column should be in int then change the format of the column to int and extract the year from the date

```
alter table postmaster_compensation alter yearcode type int using extract(year from '01/01/1845','yyyy')
```